# How to destroy a dynamically loaded component within its ts-file in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I created a dynamic component loader and it is working fine but how would I destroy the component within its ts.file?

The component that is loaded dynammically:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="destroyComp()"> Destroy</button>
```

The question is, how would the implementation of the function `destroyComp` look like? Is there a function I can call so that the component destroys itself without doing anything?

Here would be the component loader (in app component) which is working fine:

```
popups = [
    {id:1, component: TestComponent}
  ]
@ViewChild('popup', {read: ViewContainerRef}) public popup: ViewContainerRef;

loadPopupComponent(i: number, event){
    if(i == 0 || !this.popup) return;
    const component = this.popups.find(x => x.id == i).component;
    if(component){
      const target = this.popup;
      const widgetComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
      let cmpRef: ComponentRef<any> = target.createComponent(widgetComponent);
    }
  }
```

and the HTML-file

```
<ng-template #popup></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ComponentRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef) has a `destroy()` method which works just as if the component was removed from DOM

> Destroys the component instance and all of the data structures associated with it.

`cmpRef.destroy()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is, that the ```cmpRef``` is in another component. But I want to destroy the component when clicking on a button in the same component. I dont want to store the ComponentRef, that is why I want to destroy the component within its own ts-file with the help of the ```destroyComp()```function but I do not know how to implement that function

Comment: @CNIS you can store `cmpRef` in a service when creating it, that way you can access it from another component to call `destroy()` on it.

Comment: @CNIS Just saw the edit, unfortunately you have to store the reference somewhere to be able to access it, alternatively when the parent component (if any) is destroyed, its child components will also be destroyed as well

Comment: Oh thank you, I will store the variable somewhere then.